# MultiPoint Server 2011, RDP sessions are disconnecting

Tags: rdp, rds, session

We are using thin clients to RDP into a Multipoint Server.  The clients are experiencing a loss of connection that does not seem to have to do with an idle disconnect setting.  I have gone through the settings and do not find anything either local or domain that would disconnect an idle session. Sometimes it happens frequently. Sometimes it may be a day before a client gets a disconnect.

The client does not seem aware of the disconnect when the system is idle. The client when interacted with will seem to hang while it tries to reconnect.

How can I narrow down the cause? I do not see anything in the event viewer that corresponds with the disconnect.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable RDP keep-alive.  Without this setting, a typical stateful device  (firewall) connection that usually has a timeout will destroy the TCP connection for the RDP session when the timeout elapses.

When this setting is enabled, the server keep-alive prevents the stateful device from timing out the session.  This setting also helps to ensure that the remote desktop session will change the state to disconnected in the event that it is actually disconnected.  Many people set this to one minute.

Machine > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections

"This policy setting allows you to enter a keep-alive interval to ensure that the session state on the RD Session Host server is consistent with the client state.

After an RD Session Host server client loses the connection to an RD Session Host server, the session on the RD Session Host server might remain active instead of changing to a disconnected state, even if the client is physically disconnected from the RD Session Host server. If the client logs on to the same RD Session Host server again, a new session might be established (if the RD Session Host server is configured to allow multiple sessions), and the original session might still be active.

If you enable this policy setting, you must enter a keep-alive interval. The keep-alive interval determines how often, in minutes, the server checks the session state. The range of values you can enter is 1 to 999,999.

If you disable or do not configure this policy setting, a keep-alive interval is not set and the server will not check the session state."

Comment: That is actually something I set up last week in an attempt to solve this issue.  So far it does not seem to have helped with the disconnects.